# How to time relinquish an Android thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, time, block

I'm in front of a very pretty annoying problem.
I have a code to execute that can take tens of seconds. In final I need to obtain the result of that computation.

If I execute the code merely on the main thread, Android will pop up telling that the thread is blocked and asking if we want to force block.

Well the principle is normal, every OS kernel needs to know our code is still alive and not blocked.

So my question is how to inform Android we are not dead?
For instance the equivalent of a Sleep(0) or ProcessMessage() or anything... but that informs Android that we are not dead, because we are just waiting or performing something pretty long...

Please don't answer me: "let make your computation in a separate thread" since the problem would be exactly the same. The main thread would still need to sit down to know when the thread completes and its result.

Comment: The problem would not be exactly the same. The original thread could continue running the user interface while the other thread was computing. It would change the problem from a hard one (how do I do two thing at once) to an easy one (how do I keep doing the same thing I was already doing).

Answer (score 6):

You should not run any process that access a database, the internet, or takes longer then .2 seconds on the UI thread.

Asynctask is a very powerful method that allows you to thread computations, while still being able to update the UI at predetermined points. Learn to love it.

As far as letting the user know, make a please wait spinner dialog appear on the pre-execute block, and make it go away on the post execute block.

Edit: To dig into this a bit: The asynctask has three blocks that run on the UI thread onPreExecute, onPostExecute, and onProgressUpdate). In these blocks you can update the UI. Within the doInBackground block, it is its own thread, and so will not block the UI as it processes.

In practice you can set things up to notify that a process is happening in onPreExecute, notify the user of progress during a onProgressUpdate, and then present the final information/clear any please wait dialogs during the onPostExecute block. It was specifically designed to tackle the exact problem you are discussing.

Any process that locks up the system for more then 4 seconds by running on the UI thread will cause a not-responding error to be presented to the user.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: As noted below, I'll probably catch flack for this but AsyncTask gets used as *way* more of a workhorse than it should.  Many of the things that people do in AsyncTasks -- network activity in particular -- would be way better done in an IntentService.  ... and, btw, post-Honeycomb, you can't touch the network from the UI thread at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should compute in another thread and then call back to the UI thread using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html for more details.

Comment: Or you could use the tool that was built for exactly this :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll probably catch flack for this but, really, only use AsyncTask where appropriate! (read: quit it!)

Virgil Dobjanschi's answer here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

.. is really, really good.  It is a little more complicated, but it is frequently no more complicated than the actual problem.

While there aren't a lot of details in the original question, it is likely that the best way to solve the problem **is** (as all answers agree) to use a separate thread.  The best way to get to that other thread, though, is likely to be an intent fired at an IntentService.  ... and then runOnUiThread, or a Handler, to get the response back.

Comment: care to give a minute where he said that? I am not willing to watch an hour just to get the context of "quit using AsyncTask"

Comment: ASyncTask is the recommended way of doing asynchronous tasks (watch the other Google I/O presentations to hear it from the Android developers themselves - not the app team)

Comment: I figured this would be trouble.  AsyncTask is a recommended way of doing very simple asynchronous tasks.  It is neither the only, nor the best way of managing all concurrency in an app.  Yeah, "stop using them" is certainly overkill.  Consider alternatives, though.  In particular, the one I mention.

Comment: I agree with you, but you should probably edit your answer to stem the downvotes.  "quit using" is too strong.  Select the right tool is good.  The key point in Virgil's discourse is that the *misuse* of AsyncTask  is the problem.  Not AsyncTask itself which, when used correctly, is enormously useful.

Comment: You are right, Simon: edited.  It is just that *so* many questions, here on SO, are about how to use it incorrectly... :-(

Comment: Agreed, but I do think this is likely the right tool for THIS job. This would be a good thing to bring up in a post where someone is asking how to use it incorrectly.

Comment: mmm... I am thinking that something that takes 10 sec is pretty borderline, for an AT.